# similar question autocomplete on handhelds missing?

Tags: support, mobile-web

I've been using the ask title box as a suggestion locator on my PC for as long as I've used stack ("*the stack exchange*"). I thought the feature existed on three mobile version of the site, also, but I don't see it coming up. Is it possible I've disabled it by stopping a process on my phone to save battery?

On Dolphin Version 9.0.1 (Jetpack 1.0.1), Android 4.0.3 with a Softbank Aquos SMB104SH, by Sharp, build S0026.

[image]

Comment: Are you browsing the mobile version or the full version of the site? What device/OS/browser?